# Watchable star wars content besides the movies (and a few series)?

Tags: star-wars

I've seen movies 1-7, Star Wars: Clone Wars (2003), Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008), Star Wars Rebels and Lego Star Wars Films.

What more watchable content is there (besides fanmade youtube videos or gameplay/storyline etc) (if any)

???

Edit: Excluding stuff like robot chicken star wars, family guy, that 70s show etc.

Edit 2: By watchable I mean it has to be video content i.e. not a book.

Comment: The Star Wars Holiday Special, Droids TV Series, Ewoks movies and TV series, that sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Never heard of those before :). Thanks!

Comment: @Rashad -- consider yourself lucky, then -- especially the Holiday Special.

Comment: Rashad, do you mean by watchable "physically capable of being watched" ? Because usually watchable is the antonym of "unwatchable" (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwatchable), and that would exclude both the Holiday special and the Ewok movies.

Comment: There some officially-licensed but non-canon [LEGO Star Wars specials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lego_films)

Comment: Ah, yes I'll put answer this in edit so as not to confuse other viewers.

Comment: Ah and sorry I did see the lego star wars films but it didn't cross my mind when I wrote this.  I'll add that as well.

Comment: For the record, this does not fall within the close reasons for either recommendation (he means watchable in the sense of "capable of being viewed on a TV") or a list question since the number of properties is small and easily defined.

Comment: This might fall under storyline, bu I always recommend watching the short cinematic videos made for SWTOR. [here's all 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7jtLG0oyI8&ab_channel=ArtY_NagibatoR)

Comment: @Hatandboots ah yes I did see those 3 trailers and I did enjoy them but yeah I considered them as gameplay/storyline trailers for the MMORPG (if that's what you're talkin bout)

Comment: Oh yea we are talking about the same thing (just noticed the link)

Comment: Ah in defense of my question (as it stands) although it doesn't satisfy one of the "Ask about..." questions it also doesn't satisfy one of the "Don't ask about..." questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of TV series, TV films and Films set in the Star Wars universe that you haven't mentioned.

### **Films**

- [The Star Wars Holiday Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Holiday_Special)
- [Ewoks: The Battle for Endor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor)
- [Caravan of Courage: An Ewok Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravan_of_Courage:_An_Ewok_Adventure)
- [The Great Heep](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Great_Heep)

### TV Shows

- [Star Wars: Ewoks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088515/)
- [Star Wars: Droids: The Adventures of R2-D2 and C-3PO](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids:_The_Adventures_of_R2-D2_and_C-3PO)
- [Star Wars: Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Clone_Wars_(2003_TV_series)) - (Not to be confused with [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(film)) (film) or [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) (TV series))

---

### Other Stuff

It's worth mentioning that there have been several other releases of related *ephemera*;

- [Droids: The Pirates and the Prince](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pirates_and_the_Prince) (basically 4 episodes of the Droids TV series stitched together with an added voiceover to connect them)
- [Droids: Treasure of the Hidden Planet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_of_the_Hidden_Planet) (basically 4 episodes of the Droids TV series stitched together with an added voiceover and some additional footage from "The Great Heep" to connect them)
- [Star Wars: Ewoks: The Haunted Village](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Haunted_Village_(film)) (basically 4 episodes of the Ewoks TV series stitched together with an added voiceover to connect them)
- [Star Wars: Ewoks: Tales from the Endor Woods](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Haunted_Village_(film)) (basically 8 episodes of the Ewoks TV series edited together with an added voiceover to connect them)
- Each of the original Star Wars films ([ANH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)), [ESB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)#The_Empire_Strikes_Back), [RotJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)#Return_of_the_Jedi)) got their own Radio Audio production.

---

### Non-canon

There have been a number of Lego Star Wars properties that might interest you

- [Star Wars: Revenge of the Brick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Brick)
- [Lego Star Wars: The Quest for R2-D2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars:_The_Quest_for_R2-D2)
- [Lego Star Wars: Bombad Bounty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars:_Bombad_Bounty)
- [Lego Star Wars: The Padawan Menace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Padawan_Menace)
- [Lego Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Out](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Empire_Strikes_Out)
- [Lego Star Wars: The Yoda Chronicles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Yoda_Chronicles) (comprising a 7 part mini-series)
- [Lego Star Wars: Droid Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars:_Droid_Tales)

Comment: Ah perfect, the links are very helpful :), in your comment I had to google everything lol

Comment: @Richard - re: Lego Droid Tales specifically - like with the novelizations, conflicts with the film canon are considered non-canon. But, do we know if the bookend portions of the Lego Droid Tales series are indeed canon or not (considering they are post Disney and thus in some measure LucasFilm Story Group)? There are aspects that could be interesting if canon - such as the Imperial Remnant, General Veers, etc....

Comment: @NKCampbell - I've posted a [separate question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117442/20774) addressing this. In short, the answer is that the Droid Tales cartoons aren't canon, but they're more *respectful* of the existing canon and had more input from Lucasfilm.

Comment: @Richard - cool thanks. I was going to post that as an actual question initially and my pre-post searching led me to this thread. I missed the other one. Thanks!

Comment: @Rashad-Just a heads-up regarding the Star Wars Holiday Special, it gets pretty rough. Not saying anything else due to spoilers, but I'd suggest having a bottle of Tylenol or liquor nearby, whichever you' prefer; trust me, you'll be needing at least 1